# Pyschools remove Common Elements

Tags: python, list

```
def removeCommonElements(tup1,tup2):
count=0
lis1=list(tup1)
lis2=list(tup2)
while count<=len(lis1):
    for i in lis1:
        if i in lis2:
            lis1.remove(i)
            lis2.remove(i)
    count+=1
    return tuple(lis1+lis2)

print(removeCommonElements((1,2,3,4), (3,4,5,6)))
```

I need the output as `(1, 2, 5, 6)` and i'm getting an output as `(1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6)`.
I couldn't able to find my mistake. Can anyone please help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's the indenting. Indent as follows:

```
def removeCommonElements(tup1,tup2):
    count=0
    lis1=list(tup1)
    lis2=list(tup2)
    while count<=len(lis1):
        for i in lis1:
            if i in lis2:
                lis1.remove(i)
                lis2.remove(i)
        count+=1
    return tuple(lis1+lis2)

print(removeCommonElements((1,2,3,4), (3,4,5,6)))
```

Comment: I do think the indenting is just a typo of OP. The error doesn't lie here.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in lis1:
        if i in lis2:
            lis1.remove(i)
            lis2.remove(i)
```

This part of your code is looping through a list while modifying it meanwhile. So 4 is left out. You can use set to do this:

```
>>> def removeCommon(x, y):
...     x = set(x)
...     y = set(y)
...     return tuple(set.union(x, y)-set.intersection(x, y))
... 
>>> a = (1,2,3,4)
>>> b = (3,4,5,6)
>>> removeCommon(a, b)
(1, 2, 5, 6)
```